# what is difference between bionic-updates and bionic in apt source?

Tags: apt, 18.04

Is bionic-updates more stable and secure than the regular bionic when managing apt source records?

Rencently,I upgrade my server from 16 to 18 using apt-get upgrade.But I do not know how to take care of the apt source list.what I did is append the below items in the /etc/apt/sources.list.Is it enough for managing apt resources after upgrading ubuntu.

1. deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
2. deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
3. deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16 to Ubuntu Core 18 upgrades do not use `apt upgrade`  as both 16 & 18 are *snap* only products, only 16.04 & 18.04 used *deb* packages and thus `apt`, but you don't use `apt upgrade` to change releases. The *bionic* will contain original code, eg. using `linux-generic` you can see `linux-generic | 4.15.0.20.23           | bionic           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` (ie. what was on original ISOs) where as *bionic-updates* will have `linux-generic | 4.15.0.206.189         | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` or the updated package

Comment: I find this link is helpful for debian/ubuntu apt questions. see https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/apt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *bionic* repository will contain original code, eg. using `linux-generic` as an example, you can find

`linux-generic | 4.15.0.20.23           | bionic           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`

which is what you'll find on Ubuntu 18.04 *initial* LTS ISOs.

(*Ubuntu 18.04.1 & later ISOs include packages from bionic-updates as of the time of ISO creation, thus [18.04.1](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/26/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-released/) may have newer packages than initial [18.04](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/04/27/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-released/) ISO, but not as modern as say [18.04.2](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/02/15/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-released/) etc*)

The *bionic-updates* repository will have the updated code, ie.

`linux-generic | 4.15.0.206.189         | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`

I've used the following to get my detail (*note: I removed non bionic lines*)

```
guiverc@d7050-next:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   rmadison linux-generic
..
 linux-generic | 4.15.0.20.23           | bionic           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-generic | 4.15.0.206.189         | bionic-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-generic | 4.15.0.206.189         | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-generic | 4.15.0.208.191         | bionic-proposed  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

I'm not sure I'd use the word *stable* or *secure* as in your question; there are more *fixes* including security fixes in the *-updates* or *-security* repositories.

Comment: The online way of getting the detail I used would be https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all though it presents it differently with lines missing too.

Comment: I find this link is helpful for debian/ubuntu apt questions. https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/apt.html